# Managing change in object attributes while the object is being processed by another method

Tags: java, android

This is primarily a Java question. The Android tag is mostly to indicate that the method that processes the object is run on the UI thread.

Let's say I have a class named Device. And a background thread updates an instance of Device at a high frequency. On an update, the instance is passed to a method named processThisDevice(Device device).

While I am processing device, the background thread updates the instance of Device(probably several times). This change will reflect inside processThisDevice(Device device). How can I cope with this?

Would passing a deep copy of this instance to the method be a solution? Is it a good one, given the high frequency of updates?

Comment: Please, consider to clarify your question. Did you need inter-threads communications? Which object do you access simultaneously and from which parts of the code?

Comment: @avesus I don't think I need inter-thread communication. I want that no other thread should be able to modify the object instance while I am processing it. Is this requirement satisfied by user 'Viacheslav Vedenin's' answer below?

Comment: Of course it is satisfied!

Comment: @avesus Thank you, sorry about the question being confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If undestand you correctly you need to use synchronized statements:

```
void processThisDevice(Device device) {
   synchronized(device){
       ... // code what you want to do    
    }
}
```

Before you processThisDevice method complited any other processes cann't change device instance and waiting ending synchronized block. It's what you want?

Comment: Would this guarantee that 'device' will not be modified by the background thread until the 'synchronized(device){...}' block has completed?

Comment: Yes, java locked this device instance before ending of synchronized block. You can read about it in Oracle manual https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question precisely.